# understanding REALLY basic callbacks in node / js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to understand callbacks by writing a few BASIC tests to see what happens. I'm using mocha to run this.  I'm new to callbacks, obviously, but I can't see why this doesn't work.

```
import fs from 'fs';


describe('named callbacks', function() {
 it('runs something using callbacks', function() {

    function runTest() {
        return fs.readFile('test.txt', onReadFile);

        function onReadFile(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error reading file', err);
                return err;
            }
            fs.writeFile('testoutfile.txt', data, onWriteFile);
        }

        function onWriteFile(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('write error', err);
                return err;
            }
            console.log('file written!', data);
        }

    }

    runTest();
 });
});
```

The test runs, it creates the output file, but nothing gets written to it and no errors are logged.

I'm used to writing programs more top to bottom, and this callback stuff is confusing to the likes of me. I'm naming all my callbacks here so I can try to follow the logic.  I'd really like to understand WHY this doesn't work.

Comment: Might I suggest understanding callbacks without dealing with a test framework at the same time?

Comment: The test itself isn't waiting for the callbacks.

Comment: the contents of test.txt which just says 'hello world'.

Comment: SLaks - you mean the outer 'it' function or my 'runTests' function?  How do I make it wait for the callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare to Mocha that your test is asynchronous. You can do this in one of two ways: return a promise, or use the `done` callback. The code you have lends itself to the latter:

```
describe('named callbacks', function() {
 it('runs something using callbacks', function(done) {

    function runTest() {
        return fs.readFile('test.txt', onReadFile);

        function onReadFile(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error reading file', err);
                done(err);
            }
            fs.writeFile('testoutfile.txt', data, onWriteFile);
        }

        function onWriteFile(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('write error', err);
                done(err);
            }
            console.log('file written!', data);
            done();
        }

    }

    runTest();
 });
});
```

The changes are:

1. Add `done` as a parameter to the function passed to `it`.
2. Replace `return err` with `done(err)`. This passes the error to Mocha.
3. Add `done()` at the end of your `onWriteFile` function.